# Is it possible to force my iOS application to use only a certain type of UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know, if I am able to force my iOS application to use only alert notifications for it.

Or is there a way to check what kind of settings the user has for my application and act on that respectively? Or at least set a default notification type to alert when the user accepts notifications from my application first time it launches.

I would prefer an answer in SWIFT, but I would just really like to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry.There's no way we can check or set what type of notification user has set for an application.

Comment: there is this: UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings(), but it does not show whether the uses chose banners, or alerts. And that sucks :/